# How to "connect" the android watch programmatically if disconnected in the Android Wear app?

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-wear-data-api

On the top of the action bar menu, top right, in Android Wear app, I see the following item: "Disconnect HUAWEI WATCH" (this is the watch I use for testing).

If I select this item, indeed, the watch is kind of "disconnected" - there is no Bluetooth communication with it, even if the Bluetooth is in general on on and the device is still seen as paired in general Bluetooth settings. Worst, sometimes the watch gets disconnected without the user input, if it has been physically far away form the phone for longer time.

My app heavily relies on Bluetooth connectivity, and the end user most likely will not notice the fact of watch being "disconnected". They will just assume the app is buggy.

Hence it is vital for my app to detect the "disconnected watch" state. Best would be to connect the watch again, automatically or after the user confirmation. In the worse case, may be ok to detect the case and ask the user to go and fix the problem in `Android Wear`.

- How to detect programmatically that the watch has been disconnected via `Android Wear` menu.
- How to connect it back.

This is not about how to detect if Bluetooth in general is enabled or disabled, also now about how to pair the Bluetooth device.

I am using the Data API with `setUrgent()`.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest to use

```
@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int cause) {

}
```

to detect whether your nodes were disconnected.

there were

```
@Override
public void onPeerConnected(Node node) {
    Log.d(TAG, "CONNECTED");          
}

@Override
public void onPeerDisconnected(Node node) {
    Log.d(TAG, "PEER DISCONNECTED");
}
```

but now they are deprecated.

Use [CapabilityApi](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/wearable/CapabilityApi) instead

Do not forget that you can use

```
  Wearable.NodeApi.getConnectedNodes(mGoogleApiClient).setResultCallback(
                    new ResultCallback<NodeApi.GetConnectedNodesResult>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResult(NodeApi.GetConnectedNodesResult nodes) {
                            for (Node node : nodes.getNodes()) {
                            mNode = node;
                            }
                        }
                    }

            );
```

to retrieve nearby nodes

I do not know your code. That is why I just can say such broad advice.

Comment: Not complete but potentially may be helpful. Upvoting beyond doubt, will accept if nothing better comes.

Comment: getConnectedNodes works in my case. onConnectionSuspended is not called.